# Insert data in table using two or more tables

Tags: mysql

I have two existing table and wants to create third table with help of few columns. The fist two tables are;

**Table one: users**

```
 |id | name | sid   |
 | 1 | demo | test1 | 
 | 2 | anu  | test2 |
```

**Table one: insights**

```
     |     id | description| name   | 
     |     1  | yes        | demoone|   
     |     2  | no         | demotwo|
```

I want to insert data in new table called **insight_owner**. As per my knowledge, I made below query but that is giving me below error

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

The query used is

```
insert into insight_owner (column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four, column_five) VALUES ('1', '0', NULL, (select u.id from users u where u.sid='test1'), (select i.id from insights i)) ;
```

Expected output is

```
| column_one| column_two| column_three| column_four| column_five| column_six |
+----+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
|  1        |         1 |        1    |       NULL |          1 |          1 |
|  2        |         1 |        1    |       NULL |          1 |          2 |
```

column_five = Users id 
column_six = Insight id

Comment: When you insert some values in a table, it takes one tuple at a time, so when you use a select statement, it is giving more than one tuples and thus the error, try fetching only one row at a time by select like by using `Limit`, etc.

Comment: What you need to look for is to give all the values at a time, or otherwise you would need to insert them one by one using `limit`.

Comment: You are getting the error due to `(select i.id from insights i)` query which is returning more than 1 rows. Try adding a where `condition` to restrict the number of rows returned.

Comment: INSERT...SELECT syntax is probably what you're looking for (instead of INSERT...VALUES). That allows you to select the data directly from the table(s) concerned, using normal SELECT and JOIN syntax. You can also hard-code values which you want to appear on every row, just as you can in a normal SELECT statement. Basically, write the SELECT statement, get it to output what you want. Then stick an INSERT at the start of it and it sends the output to the desired table, instead of onto your screen.  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/

Comment: Yes, I want to insert all values of insights table so cannot apply limit or where clause.

Comment: @OPTIMUS see my comment above, and ysth's answer below to understand the route to a solution.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, I didn't see your comment before answering.  If you want, add an answer and I will remove mine

Comment: @ysth it was more of a clue than a solution. You've gone to the trouble of actually working out the required query, so IMHO the OP should mark yours as the accepted answer. Perhaps you could incorporate my comment into your answer as background information, so there's a record explaining to people the logic of your answer, as well as just the code.

Answer (score 3):

INSERT...SELECT syntax is what you're looking for (instead of INSERT...VALUES, which is limited to single values per column in each value list). That allows you to select the data directly from the table(s) concerned, using normal SELECT and JOIN syntax. You can also hard-code values which you want to appear on every row, just as you can in a normal SELECT statement. Basically, write the SELECT statement, get it to output what you want. Then stick an INSERT at the start of it and it sends the output to the desired table.

```
insert into insight_owner (column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four, column_five)
select '1', '0', NULL, (select u.id from users u where u.sid='test1'), i.id
from insights i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```sql
insert into insight_owner (column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four, column_five) VALUES ('1', '0', NULL, (select u.id from users u where u.sid='test1'), (select i.id from insights i));
```

Which basically inserts one row in your new table.

So, when you add subquery

```sql
select i.id from insights i
```

It will return all rows from `insights` table an you actually want just one value.

The result you will get is

```
|     id | 
|     1  |
|     2  |
```

And you want

```
|     id | 
|     1  |
```

So, you should be adding conditional that will make sure you are getting only one result as you are doing with first query (`where u.sid='test1'`), or `limit`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware that select i.id from insights is returning multiple values. In my case, I need to have rows for all columns in new table. Any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that using `INSERT INTO SELECT` statements in SQL. 

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

You can basically create the same query as above, with small adjustments but instead of `INSERT INTO VALUES` you should be using `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement. Let me know if this helps, so I can edit my answer to make sure it answers your question.